# Conflict implementing std::convert::From

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I was creating a matrix crate for personal use. It has a single struct:

```rust
use std::ops::{Add, Mul, Sub};
pub struct Matrix<T: Mul + Add + Sub> {
    entries: Vec<Vec<T>>,
}
```

I wanted to implement the `std::convert::From` trait for it. It's as simple as converting all the `S` inside `entries` to some `T` that implement `From<S>`.

But when I try to do this

```rust
use std::convert::From;
impl<T: Mul + Add + Sub, S: Mul + Add + Sub> From<Matrix<S>> for Matrix<T>
where T: From<S>
{
    ...
}
```

I get the error

```
conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<Matrix<_>>` for type `Matrix<_>`
conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
- impl<T> std::convert::From<T> for T;
```

Since negative trait bounds are [not supported in stable Rust yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42721), is there a way to implement this functionality?

Comment: no give up, I tried countless of time

Comment: Why do you think e.g. `Option` does not do this, or other containers? This is impossible.

Comment: I ended up creating my own conversion trait and implementing it for my struct.

Comment: Why won't you do something like `matrix_with_s.map(T::from)`?